# Excel vba to mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have an excel spreadsheet which works fine in the windows environment however when we try to run the same spreadsheets in MAC office 2011 the macros work but the buttons are not enabled?  They just show up as an image.  Any ideas.

Comment: What type of buttons are they - ActiveX or Forms ?  Probably need to use forms buttons to work on the Mac (but i don't have one, so can't test..)

Comment: @TimWilliams is absolutely right. You cannot use ActiveX Control in MAC. You will have to use the Form Controls.

Comment: Thanks yea you both are right I had to change each button to a form button for it to work.  But now I am trying to reference DomDocumnet and it gives an error.  Has to do with MSXML library not running on MAC.

Comment: When I created my button, I clicked on "Button (Form Control)" is this a form button? If not, how do I change it to one?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you solved the button issue in the comments by converting the buttons from ActiveX to Forms.

Regarding the reference to the Microsoft XML library, I have done LOTS of looking around the web to find something to give this functionality on the Mac Office 2011 and have found nothing.

Here are some of the other places I saw people asking this same issue:

http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-12976.html

[VBA for Mac: MSXML2.DOMDocument or System.PrivateProfileString doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499182/vba-for-mac-msxml2-domdocument-or-system-privateprofilestring-doesnt-work)

If somebody else knows how to get DOMDOCUMENT to work on Mac Office 2011, please chime in!